# session issue in cakephp2 when using custom router

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

Actually I need to make a custom url like www.{mydomainname}.com/username, for which i added

```
Router::connect('/:usrname',array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view_user_profile'),array('pass' => array('usrname')));
```

Above code solved my problem but unfortunately I lost my session on view_user_profile's view and  in elements (like header and footer). Most interesting part is that I am getting my session in function view_user_profile in controller. Session start working fine when change

Configure::write('debug', 0); to Configure::write('debug', 1);

Please help me out if you guys have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened but when i deleted php trail "?>" from my custom helper code. my problem solved.